# How do I upload a CSV file in myBucket and Read File in S3 AWS using Python

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto, bucket

How do I upload a CSV file from my local machine to my AWS S3 bucket and read that CSV file?

```
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('mybucket')
#with this i am able to create bucket
folders = bucket.list("","/")
  for folder in folders:
  print folder.name
```

Now I want to upload csv into my csv and read that file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So you're using [boto2](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html) -- I would suggest to move to [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html). Please see below some simple examples:

**boto2**

*upload example*

```
import boto 
from boto.s3.key import Key
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('mybucket')
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'myfile'
k.set_contents_from_filename('/tmp/hello.txt')
```

*download example*

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('mybucket')
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'myfile'
k. get_contents_to_filename('/tmp/hello.txt')
```

**boto3**

*upload example*

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('mybucket', 'hello.txt').put(Body=open('/tmp/hello.txt', 'rb'))
```

or simply

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

*download example*

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
print(open('/tmp/hello.txt').read())
```

Comment: And how to give permission..How to make private bucket.IF my bucket is already there.how can i make it private?

Comment: best is to work with the bucket policy directly from the aws console

Comment: Great answer. Is there a reason you prefer
```s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')```

rather than
```s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file( '/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')```
?

Comment: @Peter the `upload_file` method will let you pass an `ExtraArgs` parameter if needed (for example, set ACL permissions etc)

Comment: declaring `bucket` isn't necessary in your first upload example for boto3

Comment: @jspinella good eyes :)